# docker-compose replica hostname

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to add a cluster with replicas using `docker-compose scale graylog-es-slave=2` but for a version 3 Dockerfile unlike [Docker compose and hostname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42291409/docker-compose-and-hostname)

What I am trying to do ix figure out how to get the specific node in the replica set

Here is what I have tried

```
D:\p\liberty-docker>docker exec 706814bf33b2 ping graylog-es-slave -c 2
PING graylog-es-slave (172.19.0.4): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.19.0.4: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.067 ms
64 bytes from 172.19.0.4: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.104 ms
--- graylog-es-slave ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.067/0.085/0.104/0.000 ms

D:\p\liberty-docker>docker exec 706814bf33b2 ping graylog-es-slave.1 -c 2
ping: unknown host

D:\p\liberty-docker>docker exec 706814bf33b2 ping graylog-es-slave_1 -c 2
ping: unknown host
```

The `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: 3
service:
  graylog-es-slave:
    image: elasticsearch:2
    command: "elasticsearch -Des.cluster.name='graylog'"
    environment:
      ES_HEAP_SIZE: 2g
    deploy:
      replicas: 2 <-- this is ignored on docker-compose just putting it here for completeness
```

Comment: Could you include your docker-compose.yml please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `.`, use `_` (underscore), and add the prefix of the project name (the directory that holds your docker-compose.yml, I assume that it is `liberty-docker_graylog`):

```
ping liberty-docker_graylog-es-slave_1
```

You can see that doing `network ls`, search for the right network, then `docker network inspect network_id`.

Comment: Per OP 

D:\p\liberty-docker>docker exec 706814bf33b2 ping graylog-es-slave_1 -c 2
ping: unknown host

Comment: Sounds valid just stepped out for a moment.

Comment: Yup it works.  Though in the end I had to take it out as the docker images of Graylog or ElasticSearch that was provided do not work well with  building a multinode elasticsearch cluster.